# switch between two windows in browser using Selenium java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I'm trying to switch between windows and put an accountant to find out if the Selenium found the second window , but does not find it , note that he sees only 01 window , which is the Father window.

**how do I find It the second window and switch to It?**

I use: selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2 + Eclipse + Java 1.8

I tried this:

```
    //Get all window handles
                Set<String> allHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();

                //count the handles Here count is=2
                System.out.println("Count of windows:"+allHandles.size());      

                //Get current handle or default handle
                String currentWindowHandle = allHandles.iterator().next();
                System.out.println("currentWindow Handle"+currentWindowHandle);

                //Remove first/default Handle
                allHandles.remove(allHandles.iterator().next());

                //get the last Window Handle
                String lastHandle = allHandles.iterator().next();
                System.out.println("last window handle"+lastHandle);

                //switch to second/last window, because we know there are only two    windows 1-parent window 2-other window(ad window)
                driver.switchTo().window(lastHandle);
                System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
                driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).click();
```

message on the console:

[image: message on the console]

Comment: are you sure all the browser windows opened are webdriver instances?

Comment: @parishodak The second window is generated after a click on the button that is in the first window , so I can not clearly define whether it belongs to the instance of WebDriver , but I think so

Comment: hmm, are you trying to count window handles for IE browser?  try these options. 1) introduce wait before calling "getwindowhandles" method 2) if IE browser, introudce flakiness capability

Comment: @parishodak I did all this and yet he only recognizes a window

Any more suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue with IE 11. Solved it by checking enable protected mode settings for all zones in IE settings.

Comment: I did all this and yet he only recognizes a window

Any more suggestions?